# Harddisk serial number from terminal?

Tags: hard-disk, hardware

I have multiple hard disks which get connected to my server and I'm not sure which one is what in the view of sdXY. If I could see the serial numbers of my hard disks from terminal, I could easily identify them.

Is there any way I can get the serial numbers from the terminal?

Comment: expanding on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207386/198636) (I may not comment yet), you can even do it without grep and listing only the property value with
```
udevadm info --query=property --property=ID_SERIAL_SHORT --value --name=/dev/sda
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Another solution which does not require root privileges:

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda | grep ID_SERIAL
```

This is actually the library that `lsblk`, mentioned by don_crissti, leverages, but my version of `lsblk` does not include the option for printing the serial number.

See the [man page of `udevadm`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/udevadm.8.html) for more.

Comment: Best solution if your hard disk has died completely. Other methods don't work.

Comment: `grep ID_SCSI_SERIAL` may be what actually gives the **serial number** of the drive, as opposed to the world wide name (wwn) reported under `ID_SERIAL`.

Comment: @ron Interesting! Do you have any references that define wwn?

Comment: only reference is my first hand experience with WD, Seagate, HGST hard drives comparing values at the terminal to what is written on the label.  Hard drives are primarily enterprise/data center grade versus consumer desktop.

Comment: I had recently asked this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364456/getting-hard-disk-drive-serial-number-at-the-terminal-not-the-wwn

Comment: @ron Just tested this again. My version of udevadm (systemd 229) reports an ID_WWN field. For the drives in my system, there is also no `ID_SCSI_SERIAL` nor anything analogous (no `ID_ATA_SERIAL`):

`E: ID_SERIAL=TOSHIBA-TR150_23SC51E8J2BI ... E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=23SC51E8J2BI ... E: ID_WWN=0x5e83a97200463ff3 ... E: ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION=0x5e83a97200463ff3
`

Comment: my RHEL7 is insistant to report the WWN only!! NOt sure whats up there... `$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda | grep ID_SERIAL
E: ID_SERIAL=350000c0f01e5dabc
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=50000c0f01e5dabc
` I just realized it must be my PCIe3 SCSI card doing that!!  Putting the WWN in a serial placeholder or something...

Comment: Can u do this based on the uuid of a hard drive?

Answer (score 77):

In terminal type:

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sd? | grep 'Serial\ Number'
```

EDIT: You can also use `lshw` or `smartctl`

- lshw

  `# lshw -class disk`
- smartctl

  `# smartctl -i /dev/sda`

If you are missing those tools, just install following packages

```
# apt-get install hdparm
# apt-get install smartmontools
# apt-get install lshw
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have tested it. But its not giving the dev/sdXX . Please try to fix it. unless its good

Comment: if you take out the 'grep' part, you will get the full info as in `hdparm -I /dev/sd?`

Comment: Does not work if your hard disk has died completely and you're looking for the serial number of the faulty unit. Use @Johann's method instead.

Comment: I had to install the (apt-ly named) `hdparm` package on ARM (Raspbian on Raspberry Pi).

Comment: Use `hdparm -I /dev/sd? | grep --before-context=4 'Serial\ Number'` to correlate the serial number with the device.  It looks like the original question requests that result.

Comment: `lshw` returns all disks. You can filter the output conveniently using `jq`, like this: `lshw -C disk -json | jq 'select(.logicalname="/dev/sda")'`.

Comment: something hosed on my end, reports this for all 9 drives.. `$ hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep 'Serial\ Number'
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 80 0a 11 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 80 0a 11 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Input/output error
`

Answer (score 65):

Device<sup>1</sup> name and corresponding serial number:

```
lsblk --nodeps -o name,serial
```

output:

```
NAME SERIAL
sda  0000000012400917BA30
sdb  0000000012400917BA96
```

add `-n` if you don't want to print the header line:

```
lsblk -dno name,serial
```

output:

```
sda  0000000012400917BA30
sdb  0000000012400917BA96
```

Pass *`device`* as argument to get only the serial number of a specific device:

```
lsblk -dno serial /dev/sda
```

output:

```
0000000012400917BA30
```

---

Keep in mind `lsblk` *lists information about all available (or the specified) **block devices***. Now, for those who do not know what that last term means:
In general, *block devices* are devices that store or hold data. Diskette drives, hard drives and CD-ROM drives are all block devices. But that's not a problem when using `lsblk` as you can simply add more columns e.g `type` (device type) and/or `tran` (device transport type) etc:

```
lsblk -dno name,serial,type,tran
```

```
sda  0000000012400917BA30     disk sata
sdb  0000000012400917BA96     disk sata
sr0  4B583242334C453233353320 rom  usb
```

Comment: Note that this appears to require `lsblk` from util-linux version 2.24 or higher: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/460c7afb79075bd5b39e7d4bc153aa41c939bab3

Comment: How to retrieve hard disk serial when I use a VM ubuntu? The above commands return nothing on this situation

Comment: @BenyaminJafari the whole point of a VM is to separate the OS from the host hardware.

Comment: this also works if you're using software raid, thanks.

Comment: May I ask why `--nodeps` is necessary?

Comment: @midnite - why would you _not use_ `--nodeps` if all you need is the _drive_ serial number?

Comment: @don_crissti - Oh I see what you mean. It is because I get only the serial number by `lsblk -no serial /dev/sda`. With or without `--nodeps` gives the same output.

Answer (score 12):

By using `hdparm`
you can see your Harddisk serial number from terminal.

Open your terminal and type as

```
 hdparm -I /dev/sd?|grep -E "Number|/dev"
```

Comment: Well, but you need to be __superuser__ to use the `-I` option in `hdparm`. I would not want that either and prefer a way how to read out the ser # *without* root permissions. This is why I've upvoted don_crissti's solution only. –  syntaxerror 57 secs ago

Answer (score 10):

```
$ ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/*sda*
```

This will show you the serial number against the familiar disk name.

Comment: This is a clever approach but doesn't work on my virtual box.  It looks like the contents of the `by-id` dir are just symlinks, so `ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/` will show you what you need anyway.

Comment: This also worked for me on a debian live boot system, while all the other tools are not available from scratch, without setting up internet and apt-getting them.

Comment: even this fails on my system as mentioned above, then using the basic, as @Wildcard mentioned you can see my SCSI card may just be having a bad day.. `$ ls -al /dev/disk/by-id | grep sdh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    9 Nov 14 22:21 scsi-350000c0f01e63ff0 -> ../../sdh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   10 Nov 14 22:21 scsi-350000c0f01e63ff0-part1 -> ../../sdh1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   10 Nov 14 22:21 scsi-350000c0f01e63ff0-part9 -> ../../sdh9
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    9 Nov 14 22:21 wwn-0x50000c0f01e63ff0 -> ../../sdh
...
`

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way I know (does not require root):

```
inxi -Dplxx
```

That outputs all disks, their serials, and any extra info. -p adds partitions. -l adds labels. -u adds UUID for the partitions.

Plus it's a lot easier to remember, heh.

Sample:

```
inxi -Dxx
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 810.2GB (42.9% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sdc model: ST3160827AS size: 160.0GB serial: 5MT2HMH6
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD3200JD size: 320.1GB serial: WD-WCAMR1302926
           ID-3: /dev/sda model: ST380817AS size: 80.0GB serial: 4MR2EWBE
           ID-4: /dev/sdd model: ST3250824AS size: 250.1GB serial: 9ND08GKX
```

Note that this filters out optical drives. To see optical data:

```
inxi -Dxxd 
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 810.2GB (42.9% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sdc model: ST3160827AS size: 160.0GB serial: 5MT2HMH6
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD3200JD size: 320.1GB serial: WD-WCAMR1302926
           ID-3: /dev/sda model: ST380817AS size: 80.0GB serial: 4MR2EWBE
           ID-4: /dev/sdd model: ST3250824AS size: 250.1GB serial: 9ND08GKX
           Optical-1: /dev/sr0 model: LITE-ON DVDRW SOHW-1693S
           rev: KS09 dev-links: dvd,dvdrw
           Features: speed: 48x multisession: yes
           audio: yes dvd: yes rw: cd-r,cd-rw,dvd-r state: running
           Optical-2: /dev/sr1 model: LITE-ON LTR-52327S rev: QS0C dev-links: cdrom,cdrw
           Features: speed: 52x multisession: yes
           audio: yes dvd: no rw: cd-r,cd-rw state: running
```

Note that on my Debian system, lsblk does not show anything for serials, whether as root or user. Which is why inxi uses a much more reliable method to get that data.

```
lsblk --nodeps -o name,serial
NAME SERIAL
fd0  
sda  
sdb  
sdc  
sdd  
sr0  
sr1  

lsblk --version
lsblk from util-linux 2.25.2
```

As you can see, to lsblk, it thinks that an optical drive and floppy drive are also disks, which in a sense they are, though not really, since they don't become disks until a disk is inserted. And it shows nothing for serial, it also by the way shows nothing for other values, like label. Definitely a bug since this data is available to the system, that's where inxi gets it, direct.

Comment: The last part of your post is wrong, `lsblk` does not think they're disks, it simply lists all _block devices_. See my updated post for a clarification.  As to not showing information - this is because you're using debian which is notorius for their `lsblk` behaviour.  It works absolutely fine on archlinux so _definitely not a bug_. Also, `inxi` is just a bash script that uses other commands to get that info; it doesn't get anything "directly".

Comment: Technically correct, but in the realm of normal speech, disks is a decent way to communicate this concept. A behavior failing is of course a bug, it's irrelevant what causes is, so your comment that a buggy lsblk isn't a bug makes basically no sense. Whether the bug is debian created or not doesn't alter the fact it's a bug. Directly means without mediation, ie, from the file system, which is where inxi gets serial information. An answer should reflect the overall gnu/linux landscape, so saying for example lsblk works except in debian/buntu has no value since most users will see it not work.

Comment: This part of the answer is incorrect: *lsblk, it thinks that an optical drive and floppy drive are also disks*. In fact, lsblk lists block devices (which include hard disks, SSDs, floppy disk drives, optical disk drives, LVM logical volumes etc.), and lsblk doesn't distinguish between disks and non-disks.

Comment: FYI on Debian buster, `lsblk --nodeps -o name,serial` does display the serial numbers, I can't reproduce the bug.

Comment: lsblk is improving, but there are still some subtle issues, I'm still not going to use it as a primary data source for tools I make, but I am using it now as a secondary source, but we've already encountered inexplicable bugs using it, working on one now.

Comment: This is awesome answer.  Unfortunately i think my SCSI card is hosed.  this works for my WD SATA drives, but not the SAS drives ` ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST3000NM0035 E size: 2.73 TiB speed: <unknown> serial: N/A temp: 25 C
           ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Seagate model: ST3000NM0035 E size: 2.73 TiB speed: <unknown> serial: N/A temp: 29 C
           ID-4: /dev/sdd vendor: Seagate model: ST3000NM0043 E size: 2.73 TiB speed: <unknown> serial: N/A temp: 25 C
  ...`

Answer (score 3):

I also like using `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id` because it'll show a disk's WWN if available. The WWN is usually printed on the disk's label, so it's easy to identify.

```
root@server (16:27:58):~# ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 20 01:51 ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_250GB_S3PZNF0JB57579N -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 20 01:51 ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_250GB_S3PZNF0JB57579N-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 20 01:51 ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_250GB_S3PZNF0JB57579N-part2 -> ../../sda2
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 20 01:51 wwn-0x50014ee25ffd0a5c -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 20 01:51 wwn-0x50014ee2b554c0b4 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 20 01:51 wwn-0x5002538d427700f0 -> ../../sda
```

Comment: this was best for me as it helped ID the drives within my RAID array so when one fails I know which one to pull

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep sdX | grep wwn | awk '{print $9'}
```

This will show the `wwn-id` for the disk. The `awk` filter may need to be adjusted depending on the OS distribution and version.
I needed a scripted solution to read the `wwn-id`, which is needed for Pacemaker disk fencing.
If partitions (`/dev/sdX1` e.g.) have already been created another `grep` is needed to filter the output:

```
ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep sdX | grep wwn | grep -v sdX1 | awk '{print $9'}
```

Comment: maybe issue with my SCSI card? `$ ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep sdh | grep wwn | awk '{print $9'}                            56 }
wwn-0x50000c0f01e63ff0                                                                                     57
wwn-0x50000c0f01e63ff0-part1                                                                               58 #adata
wwn-0x50000c0f01e63ff0-part9 `

Answer (score 1):

```
strings /sys/block/${dev_name}/device/vpd_pg80 | tr -d '\040\011\012\015'
```

Attach the 'Device Identification' VPD page (0x83) and the 'Unit Serial Number' VPD page (0x80) to a SCSI device structure. This information can be used to identify the device uniquely.

[torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/scsi/scsi.c#L428](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/scsi/scsi.c#L428)

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD, one could find that information in `/var/run/dmesg`.

On systems with ATA/SATA disks, look for `ada` devices:

```
$ grep ^ada /var/run/dmesg.boot  | grep -i serial
ada0: Serial Number WD-WMC1S5694795
ada1: Serial Number WD-WMC1S5688675
```

On other systems, disk devices may be found as `da` devices, so `grep ^da ....` instead.

Rather more comprehensive output can be found via `diskinfo`, but each disk device must be queried explicitly:

```
$ diskinfo -v ada0
ada0
    512             # sectorsize
    1000204886016   # mediasize in bytes (932G)
    1953525168      # mediasize in sectors
    4096            # stripesize
    0               # stripeoffset
    1938021         # Cylinders according to firmware.
    16              # Heads according to firmware.
    63              # Sectors according to firmware.
    WDC WD10EZEX-75ZF5A0    # Disk descr.
    WD-WMC1S5694795 # Disk ident.
    ahcich0         # Attachment
    id1,enc@n3061686369656d30/type@0/slot@1/elmdesc@Slot_00 # Physical path
    No              # TRIM/UNMAP support
    Unknown         # Rotation rate in RPM
    Not_Zoned       # Zone Mode
```

Although each disk must be named explicitly, globbing is allowed, such as `diskinfo ada{0,1}`.