# reference whole disk (/dev/sda) using UUID

Tags: udev, disk, fdisk, uuid

On my system (Debian), I can see the `UUID` identifier for all of my disks partitions (i.e. `/dev/sda1`, `dev/sda2`, ..)

```
ls /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

However, I don't see the `UUID` identifier for `/dev/sda` itself. Is it possible to reference whole disk with `UUID`?

I need this because I want to reference a particular disk, and I cannot rely it will be called `/dev/sda`.

## EDIT

The solution suggested by @don_crissti is great. However, I would like the UUID to be the same for all hard disks of the same Model/Manufacturer, not unique by serial number.

Using `udevadm`, I can see the disk attributes:

```
udevadm info -n /dev/sda -a
ATTRS{model}=="Samsung SSD 840 "
ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
ATTRS{class}=="0x010700"
ATTRS{device}=="0x1d6b"
....
```

How can I generate a `UUID` from these attributes, so that same Model/Manufacturer disk will have the same `UUID` ?

Comment: UUIDs are for filesystems, not partitions. There are PARTUUIDs for partitions, but nothing for whole disks. You'll probably have to write an udev rule to give `/dev/sda` a fixed name instead.

Comment: What's interesting about this is there is now a UUID in the MBR (at least if it was created by Windows) but seemingly no way to use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The symlinks under `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` are created by `udev` rules based on *filesystems* UUIDs. If you look at `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules` you will find entries like:

```
...... ENV{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-uuid/$env{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}"
```

To reference a disk you could use the [disk serial number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121757) and the `ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}` key.
The following `udev` rule matches the drive with serial no. `0000000013100925DB96` and creates a symlink with the same name under `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="0000000013100925DB96", SYMLINK+="disk/by-uuid/$env{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}"
```

---

As to your other question... sure, you could always use `ENV{ID_MODEL}` instead of `ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}` and use a custom string for your symlink name.
The following rule matches any drive with `ID_MODEL` = `M4-CT128M4SSD2` and creates a symlink `M4-SSD-1234567890` under `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="M4-CT128M4SSD2", SYMLINK+="disk/by-uuid/M4-SSD-1234567890"
```

Note that this works fine as long as there's only one drive matching the `ID_MODEL`. If there are multiple drives of the same model, the rule is applied again for each of them and the symlink will point to the last detected/added drive.

Comment: actually, I would like the `UUID` to be the same for all disks of the same Model/Type/Manufacturer. Do you happen to know what rule to use for that? Obviously not the serial number.

Comment: please see my edit. What I am trying to accomplish: lets say my `HDD` breaks down, but I have replacement identical disk. I replace it and I would like to have same `UUID` as before (even though the serial number has changed). I do not intend to use both disk at the same time.

Comment: @MichaelBoies - you can directly alter the UUID w/ `gdisk` - but I'm not sure if that's such a good idea. don - directly altering the links is a way better way to do it than actually altering the UUID - the computer would probably stop booting.