# Extract serial number from hdparm output

Tags: command-line, grep

I am trying to automate the use of `shred` and putting the output into log files. Currently I am copying the serial number manually using

```
hdparm -I /dev/sd? | grep 'Serial\ Number'
```

I know that there is a way to have `grep` give me only the number and not the "Serial Number" text before it but I don't know how. Could someone how knows reg expressions help me?

Comment: See my answer on [Harddisk serial number from terminal?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121757)

Answer (score 5):

Try `awk` instead of `grep`:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sd? | awk '/Serial Number/ { print $3 }'
```

or specify separator rather than accepting default of whitespace

```
hdparm -I /dev/sd? | awk -F':' '/Serial Number/ { print $2 }'
```

Comment: The second form has the disadvantage of leaving all the spaces between the colon and the serial number.

Answer (score 3):

As that xkcd strip mentions perl, let's have a perl solution:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sd? | perl -nle '/Serial Number:\s+(.+)$/ && print $1'
```

A perl version of the `awk` solution in the other answer:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sd? | perl -anle '/Serial Number:/ && print $F[2]'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
hdparm -I /dev/sd? | grep -oP 'Serial Number:\s*\K.*'
```

This uses [positive lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/639/lookahead-and-lookbehind#t=201609021621439470973) to ignore pattern before our required string.. in this case `Serial Number:\s*`

Answer (score 1):

sed?

```
hdparm -I /dev/sd? | sed -n 's/^.*Serial\ Number:  *\(.*\)$/\1/p'
```

(probably lots of other ways to do this using sed - this is just one way that I like: suppress the default print; match the required portion of the line; replace the entire line with it; then print it out.)