# Getting hard disk drive serial number at the terminal - not the WWN

Tags: linux, hard-disk, hardware, administration

WWN = **world wide name**

#### Seagate Constellation ES, model ST3500514NS, a 500 GB 3.5" SATA drive

It has "serial number", 9WJxxxxx which is eight characters. It has WWN 5000C5002E47xxxx which is a 16 characters. Both are printed on the label on the hard disk drive.

#### WD model WD4001FFSX, a 4 TB SATA drive

It has "serial number" WMC5D0Dxxxxx which is 12 characters. It has WWN 50014EE003Fxxxxx which is 16 characters.

#### HGST, model HUC109060CSS600, a 300 GB 2.5" SAS drive

It has "serial number" KWJTxxx, also eight characters. It has WWN... I don't know; it is not printed on the label and not plugged into the system to find out.

---

For inventory, we generally write down and track the following, which can always be gathered from the label on the drive:

- Manufacturer
- Model number
- Serial number
- Size in GB or TB, and connection type which is either SATA or SAS
- Location where in use, or in storage when not in use

The problem arises obviously 1, 2, 3 years later when an inventory sheet shows whatever hard drive. You are pretty sure it's in a running server, but you don't want to shut down the server to pull the hard drive to read the label.

How do you get the **serial number** of the drive that corresponds to what is on the label?

`udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda` has **ID_SERIAL**, but that is the WWN. We don't want another field to track the 16 characters of the WWN as an identifier... And I already hate writing down the long serial numbers of WD drives.

Is there a way in Linux to extract the **serial number** of the drive?

I believe it is possible because years ago the RAID storage manager GUI we had been using nicely reported the eight-character serial numbers of Seagate drives that were in use. And that RAID hardware has listed a bunch of Seagate-specific hard disk drives that were "officially supported", and if memory serves, really no other make/model of drives.

Is it possible this is hard disk drive firmware related, meaning it can be done on certain make drives and not others?

Comment: There is a problem not mentioned here: _Does the drive report a serial that matches what's physically printed on the label?_

There are definitely some drives in my experience where this is NOT true.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming the disk supports SMART, you should be able to retrieve the disk serial number using `smartctl -i /dev/sdX`

Comment: `smartctl -a /dev/sdc | grep Serial` seems to give me the result I was looking for.  It seems to be very important that `/dev/sd?` is a single drive, and not a mounted volume or any kind of storage unit, otherwise the value for Serial is bogus.  This is on a 2U server holding 16 drives, `/dev/sdc` is the OS and is configured as JBOD, 7 other drives are RAID5 via LSI raid card, 8 others are RAID5 via 2nd LSI card.

Comment: @ron `not a mounted volume or any kind of storage unit`  would logically follow given that `/dev/sda` is a physical device but `/dev/sda1` is a *partition* and `/` is a mount point

Answer (score 12):

You can get the serial number through :

1) `hdparm`:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep Serial
```

2) `sginfo` is a part of [`sg3-utils`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=sg3-utils&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) package:

```
sginfo -a /dev/sda | grep Serial
```

3) `sdparm` command :

```
sdparm -i /dev/sda | grep 'vendor specific'
```

4) `lshw`:

```
lshw -class disk -class storage | grep serial
```

Comment: ([Space before colon](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645).)

Comment: How to retrieve hard disk serial when I use a VM ubuntu? The above commands return nothing on this situation

Answer (score 6):

I only have WD drives to check on now, but `udevadm info --query=all` shows
both `ID_SERIAL`/`ID_SERIAL_SHORT` (something like `WD-WMATV6212345` and `ID_WWN` (`0x50014ee051234567`). Isn't the first what you are looking for?

`smartctl -i` also shows both, `hdparm -i` just the serial.

Comment: so `hdparm -i /dev/sdc` which is my one operating system drive results in `HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid exchange`  and  `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Invalid argument`.  I have been completely unable to get hdparm to work at all, this is on SLES 11.4.

Comment: so `udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdc` does give the serial number value I am looking for, it is tied to `ID_SCSI_SERIAL`.  The value for any of the others is all the same and is the WWN.

Comment: That was on an HGST drive where `ID_MODEL` is also reported correctly as `HUC109060CSS600`.

Comment: for a Seagate ST9300603SS, `ID_SCSI_SERIAL` reports a 20 character serial number, with the first 8 characters matching to the serial number on the label.

Answer (score 4):

The lshw program shows it, at least with html output

```
sudo lshw -C disk -html > /some/place/hw.html
```

The relevant section on my hardware for one of my disks -

```
id: disk
description:    ATA Disk
product:    ST32000542AS
vendor: Seagate
physical id: 0.0.0
bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
logical name: /dev/sda
version:    CC34
serial: 5XW2PB56
size:   1863GiB (2TB)
capabilities:   partitioned partitioned:dos
configuration:  
  ansiversion   =   5
  logicalsectorsize =   512
  sectorsize    =   512
  signature =   d46cf327
```

Comment: The `-html` option is not needed.