# Is there a way to modify the VENDOR and MODEL fields of removable storage units you can list with the following LINUX lsblk command?

Tags: linux, bash, udev, disk

Command:

```bash
lsblk -l -e7 -o RM,TYPE,PATH,NAME,VENDOR,MODEL |\
awk '{ if ( ($1 == 1) && ($2 == "disk") ) {print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6} }'
```

Context/limitations regarding my question:

1. The LABEL field, which can be requested with

```bash
lsblk -l -e7 -o RM,TYPE,NAME,LABEL |\
awk '{ if ( ($1 == 1) && ($2 == "part") ) {print $2,$3,$4} }'
```

concerns the partition(s) and can be changed with `fatlabel`, `e2label`, `ntfslabel` . . . ; this is not what I am looking for.

2. The volume-label  mentioned in the man page of `tune2fs` command seems to actually be the partition label.
   The command `tune2fs -l  PATH` only works with a PATH including a **magic number**, therefore a partition (not a disk).
3. Why do I suspect I miss some knowledge or information in this matter?
   A device/volume/PATH(without magic number) can encompass several partitions ; therefore, I do not see any other specific identifier for the hardware device than the `VENDOR` and `MODEL` fields.  If you use several usb sticks from the same manufacturer (my case), it is getting confusing and I found nothing on the web.

My regards to the experienced contributors on this site ; I owe them much of the modest progress I booked on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: what do you mean by "magic number"? What is it you are actually trying to achieve by "modifying the vendor and model fields" (note: you can NOT change those) - so, what is the end goal, perhaps someone can suggest an alternative

Comment: So, you are trying to differentiate drives that have the same vendor and model ID when running `lsblk`? Just [add `SERIAL` to the `-o` fields to get the serial no. of the drive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169554) which should be unique.

Comment: Attn JAROMANDA : the magic number is the last character (a digit, the x in /dev/sdbx) which specifies the partition in a block device identification ; I say "magic" because it is what Bash tells me when I do not type the digit in where needed.  NOW, you answered the question and I THANK YOU.   More details, attn DON_CRISSTI, about the context of my  question : imagine a display of a tree structure with HW devices=>Partitions=>Directories (several possible items per mother branch) and the same identification for the USB keys ; which one refers to which port on the machine ?